# Text Classification - How to transform and fit multiple string features into a machine learning model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-classification

In my dataset there are 3 input columns(Manufacturer,short text,supplier) from which I wish to create a  vectorize feature list. And then I am expecting to fit the same into a machine learning model. Last column (category) is the label. I have 2 million rows in the dataset.
I am unable to vectorize all three columns at once.

Data sample

[image]

```
train_X, test_X, train_Y, test_Y = model_selection.train_test_split(df[["Manufacturer", "short text", "supplier"], df['category'],test_size=0.15, random_state=500)

train_X = pd.DataFrame(data = train_X)
train_Y = pd.DataFrame(data = train_Y)
test_X = pd.DataFrame(data = test_X)
test_Y = pd.DataFrame(data = test_Y)


# creating SVM model
text_clf_svm    =   Pipeline([('vect',  CountVectorizer(lowercase=True, preprocessor= None, tokenizer= None, ngram_range=(1,6), stop_words= 'english', analyzer='word', max_df=1.0, min_df=1, max_features=None, vocabulary=None, binary=False)),       
                              ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),            
                              ('clf-svm',   SGDClassifier(loss='modified_huber',    penalty='l2',shuffle=True,      
                               alpha=0.000001,  max_iter=9, random_state=None)),])      


#running training data on svm model
text_clf_svm1 = text_clf_svm.fit(train_X, train_Y)
```

**Error**

```
Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples
```

Please let me know how to vectorize all 3 columns together.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try collapsing `Manufacturer`, `short text` and `supplier` into one column and use that to train your model. At least this is what I did with a classification problem where I had product names and three different categories.

Comment: @anddt - I have already tried that and its working perfectly fine. But I want to understand how can I fit the same into a machine learning model while keeping the columns separate.

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't believe that makes much sense. `TfidfTransformer` builds a frequency array for each word in your column. Applying it on each of your columns will obviously produce arrays of different length (not every word appears in all of your columns, hence the importance of merging them). Hope this helps.

Comment: but if you collapse the different columns into one another, wouldnt it be confusing for the model? or at least it wont be able to determine the significance of any independent variables ie. (features). Unless I'm missing something as I'm just starting to learn and have come across this exact issue in my assignment

Answer (score 0):

You're basically asking how to `vectorise data`. 
There are different types of data (eg: tabular data, text data, image data, ...) and for each data type one can use different vectorisation techniques. Tabular data can be made of categorical variables (vectorised with one-hot encoding) or continuous variables (vectorised with normalisation). Text data can be vectorised with for example Bag of words or TF-IDF.

In the case of your dataset, here are the data types of each column:

- Manufacturer, supplier, category = categorical
- short text = text

I understand it can be confusing because your categorical features are made of strings hence one can think at first sight it's text.
But you have basically 2 ways forward:

1. you view "Manufacturer" and "supplier" as categories, and you use `CountVectorizer` on "short text" only. Then you concatenate the vectorisation of all features together, and feed that into a model
2. Or, as suggested in the comments, you concatenate the 3 columns together, and treat the resulting string as a new text column, that you vectorise with a `CountVectoriser` and then pass to a model

Those 2 approaches are different and the first one can be very interesting to master as it can prove handy for more complicated datasets in the future.

Comment: Do you have further references/examples of how to work with the first approach you presented? 

Most of books/articles I read treat the text data as a huge block of text. In case of emails, for instance, you have a title/body/etc., it is nice to have different weights for each feature in this case. It would be nice to know best practices to work with this kind of setup, but I hardly find any reference :/

Comment: @d4nielfr4nco You could use [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) combined with [FeatureUnion](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) to achieve what I was describing. In FeatureUnion, you can pass custom weights for each transformers as well.